# Instagram like Login Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am making a app where you can login and I want the username and password to be as this picture shows. I already tried android:text="" but if you do that you need to erase it but I want it to erase itself when you begin typing. 
Probably a stupid question but I just began with android studio so yeah

Answer (score 4):

This is hint, if it is edit text you could do like this programaticaly

```
myEditText.setHint("Username");
```

or in xml:

```
android:hint="Username"
```

**EDIT**

This is your code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etusername" 
 android:hint=""  
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your `android:hint=""` add text Username, Password or something you wish, and make it like this `android:hint="Username"`.

Comment: Where should I put the "myEditText.setHint("Username");"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etusername"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: @Ryan Illes accept answer if it was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
    android:hint="UserName"/>
```